# Rename ARM assembly register in XCode 5.1 / LLVM / clang

Tags: ios, xcode, assembly

I have an AArch64 NEON function defined in an assembly `.s` file. It's already compiling and running fine, but to improve code readability I'd like to use register aliases with the `.req` assembler directive. Although when I try to do it clang fails with *error: unexpected token in argument list*

To keep the example simple consider this code:

```
    .section __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .globl   _foo
    .align   2
_foo:
    add      w0, w0, w1
    ret      lr
```

This code compiles and runs, but if I try to use

```
    myreg    .req w0
```

before the `add` instruction, I get

```
/Users/dfcamara/Desktop/MyApp/MyApp/foo.s:5:16: error: unexpected token in argument list
    myreg .req w0
               ^
```

Maybe I need some clang directive that I'm not aware, I can't find documentation about them. Or a compiler option. I just created a new iOS (iPad) project and added an assembly file.

Thanks

Comment: You didn't say what assembler you are using. `GNU as` version 2.24 seems to support the syntax you showed, in fact that's the example in the [documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.24/as/AArch64-Directives.html).

Comment: Yes, my background is from `GNU as` and I'm new on MacOS and iOS. XCode uses LLVM compiler and AFAIK the assembler is clang.

Comment: Oh, didn't know clang had an integrated assembler. The [web page](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html) says it is `extremely compatible with GAS` ... well, maybe not that extremely, then ;)